# How to Check Two Option Set Value in Dynamics CRM Using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin that triggered to run on Update based on the value of the Two Option Field. If the value is "Yes" then the plugin will run.

I tried to use `entity.FormattedValues["fieldname"].toString()` to get the text value from the Two Optionset Field. But didn't work.

I don't think that QueryExpression is not suit in my case.CMIIW

Here is my full code:

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity entity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;

            if (entity.LogicalName != "incident")
                return;

            string str = entity.FormattedValues["new_createticket"].ToString();

            if (str == "Yes")
            {
                Entity ticket = new Entity("new_troubleticket");
                ticket["new_subject"] = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("title");
                Guid ticketid = service.Create(ticket);

                entity["new_troubleticketid"] = new EntityReference("new_troubleticket", ticketid);
                entity["new_createticket"] = false;
            }

            service.Update(entity);
        }
```

If you have any solution, please share with me
Best regards

Comment: If you are executing on an update message are you sure you are sending the attribute over in the Entity Image ? as if it is not then the value you will be receiving is a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `Register` your plugin on `Update,Post-Operation`. In the plugin context, `Target Entity` you will only get the fields which are updated. To get other fields that are required for your custom business logic You have two options.

```
1.  Retrieve the Entity by Guid with all the required attributes
2.  Register a Post-Entity Image to get all the attributes.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_preandpost

**Taken from the Above Url:**

Registering for pre or post images to access entity attribute values results in improved plug-in performance as compared to obtaining entity attributes in plug-in code through RetrieveRequest or RetrieveMultipleRequest requests.

Now coming to your code/logic problem. 
In CRM you should have created the `Two-Option` correctly, by this I mean

By Default when we create field of  Data Type `Two Options` it has two Options

```
1. Label=No and Value=0
2. Label= Yes and Values=1
```

If you have set the Text ='Yes' and value =1 for `new_createticket`, then change your code to this

```
 //string str = entity.FormattedValues["new_createticket"].ToString();
 Entity entity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
```

Now here is the tricky part, the above `entity` may contain `new_cr‌​ea‌​teticket` field, if it is changed, but if it is not changed then it will not be present. Here you can either do this

```
Entity updatedEntity = _service.Retrieve(entity.LogicalName,entity.Id,new ColumnSet("new_cr‌​ea‌​teticket","title"))
if (updatedEntity.GetAttribute‌​‌​Value<bool>("new_cr‌​ea‌​teticket") == true)
  {
     Entity ticket = new Entity("new_troubleticket");
     ticket["new_subject"] = updatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<String>("title");
     Guid ticketid = service.Create(ticket);

updatedEntity["new_troubleticketid"] = new EntityReference("new_troubleticket", ticketid);
    updatedEntity["new_createticket"] = false;
  }
```

**The Above code should work fine if you verify that `new_createticket` is a Two-Option field, and on update your are either retrieving it or passing it in the Post-Entity Image.**

Comment: Thank you, your answer is solution for me. Also you give me a new knowledge about CRM plugin. Especially about retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Formatted values are for displaying purposes, but the actual boolean value you need exists as an attribute.

Try

```
if(entity["fieldname"] == true)
```

Comment: u can't use that for boolean type. In order to do that, you have to use this `entity.GetAttributeValue<bool>("new_createticket") == true`. But it's still dont work.

Comment: if `entity.GetAttribute‌​Value<bool>("new_crea‌​teticket") == true` doesn't work means that the field is not a two options or the value stored inside the entity is null or false.

Comment: @FikriHailal, I've doing that for ages .... it does work, assuming your field is a two options field, of course, as Guido said

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure, but try using with the .equals() method instead of the equality operator.

So:

```
if (str.equals("Yes")) {
  // DO ANYTHING
}
```

However, you should still use the equality operator `==` for integers.